# How do I find the file and line number of a CrossRider error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-extension, crossrider

We are using CrossRider to develop an extension for Internet Explorer. I tested our extension in debug mode on https://email14.secureserver.net/webmail.php?login=1, and I receive an error message.

Which file does this error come from? We have many files in our resources. How do I identify which file and line this error comes from?

Our Extension ID is 43889. I'm using Internet Explorer 11 but this extension should work on all versions of Internet Explorer.

**Edit**: I found out that the error comes from this line:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {}, false);
```

It only happens on https://email14.secureserver.net/webmail.php?login=1, not on other websites. Anyway I disabled this line in CrossRider.

Comment: Internet Explorer extensions are notoriously difficult to debug. I would start by taking a look at the console for any error messages thrown by the extension API. It really useful to have ample meaningful log messages to help you trace where the problem might exist. Also, you may find the following Crossrider blog of interest: [Tips & Tricks for Debugging your Crossrider Extensions](http://blog.crossrider.com/post/100751262257/tips-tricks-for-debugging-your-crossrider) [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: @Shlomo Thanks for your comment, I used console logs and alerts and found the line that caused this error, please see my updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the update ... I would guess the site or the page is restricting access to the event listener.

Comment: If the website is using IE compatibility mode that could be the reason for the error

Comment: @Bnaya How can I detect if `email14.secureserver.net` is using an old mode of Internet Explorer?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and i think also window.compatibilityMode

Comment: @Bnaya Thank you. `email14.secureserver.net` is using document mode = 7, while other websites are using Edge. I think this is the reason why I can't define `window.addEventListener`.

Comment: Well that means they rendering their website as IE7 and the browser is running like he is IE7 and IE7 dose not support postMessage or addEventListener.

BTW IE8 support postMessage but not addEventListener.

There are simple polyfills for addEventListener but for postMessage its more a problem